# How to set different users for different pages?

Tags: plugins, pages, users, subscription

I am designing a site in which I wish to have different users (logged in) for different pages.

Illustration:

Suppose I have subscribers A,B,C,D,E,F and pages 1,2 and 3.

I wish to have the follwing functionality:

A can access pages 1,2 and not 3 B can access pages 1 and not 2 and 3 C can access all pages.

I tried using the following plugins:

Capability Manager
Contexture page security
members
User access manager
user groups
page restrict (This can restrict the access of anonymous to certain pages and only logged in users can view locked pages.)
But I'm not able get the functionality I require even after using any combinations of above plugins.

Require some help, I'm a newbie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This - again - might be easier with a multisite/network install. Simply add different users to different sites.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is ther any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a subfolder in plugins folder, name it 'MyRestict'. In This folder put the following php:

   ```
   <?php 
   /**
    * Plugin Name: My Restict
    * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112566/how-to-set-different-users-for-different-pages
    * Author: G.M.
    */

   function my_restict_template_filter( $template ) {
     if ( is_page() ) {
       $post = get_queried_object();
       $allowed = (string) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'allowed_users', true);
       if ( $allowed ) $allowed = array_map('trim', explode(',', $allowed) );
       $user = wp_get_current_user();
       if ( ! empty($allowed) && ( ! is_object($user) || ! in_array($user->ID, $allowed) ) )
         return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'not-allowed.php';
     }
     return $template;
   }

   add_filter('template_include', 'my_restict_template_filter');
   ```
2. In the same 'MyRestict' folder create a file named `not-allowed.php` and there put something like:

   ```
   <div>Sorry, you are not allowed to view this page.</div>
   ```
3. In your pages you have to create a custom field with the key `allowed_users` where you have to write comma separed list of **users ids** of users that you want to allow viewing that page:
   [image]
4. Activate the 'My Restict' plugin in the backend

Remember that pages that do not have any custom field will be accessible to all visitors, even not logged ones.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I tried doing what you mentione but the above plugin does not produce any effect.

Comment: @rockswap there was a little error on my code. I've corrected, now it should works.

Comment: That worked amazingly. Thank you. :) Sorry, I dont have enough reputation to vote up. Once I have I'll vote up.

Comment: @rockswap glad it works.